# Module Not Found error while running a program in NeST software

Tags: networking, server, ethernet, client, traffic

I tried to run with   **`$ sudo python3 p2p.py`**

But it shows an error in my machine .

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module name nest**

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run with   **`$ sudo python3 p2p.py`**

But it shows an error in my machine .

Then I execute the command  **`$ sudo -E python3 p2p.py`**
and it works.

The -E option is required because of the way NeST is installed. Typically, python packages are installed either globally or per user.

It looks like for most users, NeST gets installed for the user only in Ubuntu (not globally). So when you run "sudo python p2p.py", python will search for NeST package globally, and this will throw an error. So we add a "-E" option for sudo, so that it will consider the current user's environment also while running as root, and thus NeST package will be found.

[See the Picture for Better Understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPvnV.png)

Comment: @David this is a self-answer, which is allowed.